# Informing observers of LiveData Firebase Realtime Database elements are deleted

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata

As I know the `ChildEventListener` is the only way to detect that data in Firebase Realtime Database was deleted. That's why I extend `LiveData` to handle the events of `ChildEventListener`.

```
public class UserRatingsLiveData extends LiveData<DataSnapshot> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "UserRatingsLiveData";

    private final Query query;
    private final UserRatingsChildEventListener listener = new UserRatingsChildEventListener();

    public UserRatingsLiveData(DatabaseReference ref) {
        this.query = ref;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActive");
        query.addChildEventListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onInactive");
        query.removeEventListener(listener);
    }

    private class UserRatingsChildEventListener implements ChildEventListener {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            setValue(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            setValue(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // What to do here to signale that the element was removed?

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "entering onCancelled(...)");
        }
    }
}
```

Delegating newly created elements in `onChildAdded(...)` with `setValue(dataSnapshot)` is straight forward. But what's with signaling that an element was removed?

Should I use a special LiveData object only for the remove event?

Any other idea?